# How to show a specific contents in PHP?

Tags: php, content-type

In my hosting contain some files: 1.txt, 2.txt,...,1000.txt
When I type access ANY URL which contain number, the content of file which is corresponding to that number will be showed.

For example: When I access:

```
http://mywebsite.com/something-9-keyword ----> content of 9.txt will be showed
http://mywebsite.com/2-anything-keyword ------> content of 2.txt will be showed
http://mywebsite.com/how-to-show-content-3 ------> content of 3.txt will be showed
```

How to do that with PHP ? Thank you very much !

Comment: what have you done so far? use htaccess for redirecton  to a php file which will get content of chosen file

Comment: @Aleksandar Vasić, How to use htaccess to redirect ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Option #1)** Getting the file ID using an Apache .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*?(\d+).* %{QUERY_STRING}?textFileId=$1 [L]
```

(and then in PHP)

```
$textFileId = $_GET['textFileId'];
```

**(Option #2)** Getting the file ID using only PHP:

```
if(preg_match("#.*?(\d+).*#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    $textFileId = $matches[1];
}
```

---

Once that's sorted, you can include the text file within your PHP/HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
(etc, etc)
<body>
    <div id="stuff">
        <?php include("$textFileId.txt"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put a .htaccess file in the root directory of your domain containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*?(\d+).* $1.txt [L]
```

This'll scan and rewrite the request like you mentioned before. Keep in mind that only the first number will be used, so `/something-91-keyword-43-foo` will be rewritten to `/91.txt`.

I'm assuming:

- Your website is hosted using Apache
- Your domain's Apache configuration has "AllowOverride All" set for the directory you're putting the .htaccess file in

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! However, I want to use php file because I have something more such as html tag, css file to add. The .txt file only contain text. How to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure what's in your .txt files should be just text, no HTML? It sounds to me like your .txt files would be more like .html files because they are articles for your website, which would contain paragraphs (i.e. `<p>` tags) and such. Anyway, just assuming you want to grab a raw text file for inclusion in PHP, see my other answer.

Comment: Yes, .txt is just raw test file